# Reading Pdf file that contains tablular formate data and store into key value formate

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I want to extract tabular data from the PDF file, I don't get the idea how to read the tabular data in java in the form of key-value, Can any one give the idea related to reading the table content PDF file.  My input PDF is

[image]

I want to store the data in the form of key-value format. Example:

```
key              value
Invoice No.      97034978
Invoice Date     22.02.2017
```

Text file:

```
    Invoice No. Invoice Date Due Date     Amount 
    97034978 22.02.2017 22.02.2017 INR 3,972,349.26
    Excise Details : 
    KRISHNA MARUTI Registration Number : AAFCM1225REI009
    Range & Addon : RANGE 40
    Division : CENTRAL EXCISE DIVISION-VIII
//...
```

From text file i didn't recognize the key value data.

I know many questions related to this topics, but I didn't get the solution. So please help to find the way..

Comment: Which Java PDF library do you use?

Comment: @mkl I use pdfbox

Comment: Can you share the sample pdf (not an image of it but the actual pdf)?